# dalelotts datetimepicker multiple on page

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, datepicker, datetimepicker

Using the [following datetimepicker](https://github.com/dalelotts/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker), is it possible to place multiple on screen to capture a **start / end datetime**?

This is the code for the datetimepicker

```
 <div class="dropdown">
   <a class="dropdown-toggle my-toggle-select-end" id="dLabel" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#" href="">
    <div class="input-append"><input type="text" class="input-large" data-ng-model="data.date"><span class="add-on"><i                          class="icon-calendar"></i></span> </div></a>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
       <datetimepicker data-ng-model="data.date" data-datetimepicker-config="{ dropdownSelector: '.my-toggle-select-end' }"></datetimepicker>
     </ul>
    </div>
```

Edit : I was able to use [Angular Bootstrap UI](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) Date picker / Time picker separate and that worked but it would be better UX / design wise to have them as one component.

Update: I will attempt to use the [following directive](https://github.com/Gillardo/bootstrap-ui-datetime-picker)
Update - Solved using Gillardo's DateTimePicker.

Answer (score 0):

Solved using Gillardo's DateTimePicker.

Answer (score 0):

There is an example in the [readme file](https://github.com/dalelotts/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker#create-a-date-range-picker-with-validation-controls) of how to do this using https://github.com/dalelotts/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker